# Does it make sense to put a lengthy subject after "for" and use "they" to refer to it

Tags: spoken-english

I always hear sentences like below in conversations with English learners.

> For successful people in the world, they always work hard.
>
> For most employees in the sales department, they have a good income.

Basically it's like "For SUBJECT, they do...", and the subject is usually long.

They can be rephrased to

> Successful people in the world always work hard.
>
> Most employees in the sales department have a good income.

Does this type of sentence construction even make sense? Is it allowed or common in informal speaking English, especially when the subject is quite long? Or should we try our best to avoid it?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker but I have not heard this structure. To be honest, if you had not rephrased the text, I would not have understood them.

Comment: It is not correct (though even native speakers occasionally end a long sentence in a way that doesn't quite fit the beginning). _For [a person]_ means _from the point of view of that person_, so you could say **For most employees in the sales department, their salary is enough for them to live comfortably.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!